# Braintree Webhook Methods

Tags: php, webhooks, payment, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm fetching a Webhook that is coming from Braintree. The Webhook is return a success and also creates the log file. This is the code I'm using:

```
if( isset($_POST["bt_signature"]) && isset($_POST["bt_payload"])){

        $webhookNotification = \Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
            $_POST["bt_signature"], $_POST["bt_payload"]
        );

        $message = "[Webhook Received "
        . $webhookNotification->timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] "
        . "Kind: " . $webhookNotification->kind . " | "
        . "Payment ID: " . $webhookNotification->localPaymentCompleted->paymentId . "\n";

        file_put_contents("/tmp/webhook.log", $message, FILE_APPEND);

        // if everything went fine, send confirmation to the buyer
        $this->artikelRepository->sendConfirmationAction(null, $webhookNotification->localPaymentCompleted->paymentId);
    }
```

To confirm the payment I need the `paymentId` of the local payment. I tried with various methods, but this should work: `$webhookNotification->localPaymentCompleted->paymentId` according to the [test file](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/tests/unit/WebhookNotificationTest.php).

The log file returns this, though:

[image]

How am I able to retrieve the Payment ID of a local payment inside the webhook function?

**Update: I just noticed that we used a totally outdated SDK. The functions we tried to use were not even added in the old version.**

Comment: You should dump out the value of `$webhookNotification` and make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: @ceejayoz But what is the best way to debug a webhook if I have no clue what data is being returned? The Braintree API Docs really sucks regarding this. I tried to send me the output via email and also with the log file mentioned in my post. Nothing I can work with or any insights into the response.

Comment: That's the point. Dumping the value of `$webhookNotification` allows you to see what data's being sent to you.

Comment: @ceejayoz I understand what dumping the output means and what it is good for. The thing is: how? var_dump($webhookNotification) does not work, sending an email with json_decode or anything returns nothing. So I'm not sure how to dump the response object.

Comment: I'd log the raw `$_POST["bt_payload"]` somewhere.

Comment: The bt_payload does not include any helpful data.

Comment: What **does** it contain? Clearly enough to get `local_payment_completed` into `$webhookNotification->kind`, so what else is in the payload?

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah man, the PHP SDK we used was way outdated. The functions we tried to use were not even added in the old version. Sorry about that and thanks for your help.